# Why does Firebase Auth work on emulator but not on real device

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app where the user can login using their mobile number. I used Firebase Auth for this. It works like a charm on the emulator.It runs fast and the app works well. But, when I try that on my Samsung M30s, it does not login. This is my code:

```java
package com.sk.telegram.Activities.Login;

import static android.view.View.GONE;
import static android.view.View.VISIBLE;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseTooManyRequestsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.sambhav2358.tinydb.TinyDB;
import com.sambhav2358.tinydb.TinyDBManager;
import com.sk.telegram.Activities.MainActivity;
import com.sk.telegram.Models.User;
import com.sk.telegram.Utils.KeyUtils;
import com.sk.telegram.Utils.PreferenceManager;
import com.sk.telegram.Utils.TextUtils;
import com.sk.telegram.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityLoginBinding binding;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    String mVerificationId;
    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
    PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    boolean isLoggedIn = false;
    
    Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        init();
        binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!isLoggedIn) {
                isLoggedIn = true;
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Please wait...");
                startPhoneNumberVerification(getPhoneNumber());
            }else {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Please wait...");
                verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId,binding.otp.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void init(){
        binding.countryCodePicker.setAutoDetectedCountry(true);
        // [START initialize_auth]
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [END initialize_auth]

        // Initialize phone auth callbacks
        // [START phone_auth_callbacks]
        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
                // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
                //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
                // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
                //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
                //     user action.
                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "verified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
                // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
                Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "There was and error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    // Invalid request
                } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                    // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                }

                // Show a message and update the UI
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId,
                                   @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                // by combining the code with a verification ID.
                Log.d("LoginActivity", "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);
                //dismiss the dialog and update the UI
                dialog.dismiss();
                binding.phoneAuthLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                binding.otpLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                mVerificationId = verificationId;
                mResendToken = token;
            }
        };
        // [END phone_auth_callbacks]
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {
        // [START start_phone_auth]
        PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                        .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
        // [END start_phone_auth]
    }

    private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
        // [START verify_with_code]
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        // [END verify_with_code]
    }

    private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                        PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
        PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                        .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .setForceResendingToken(token)     // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                            User mUser = new User("User" + new Random().nextInt(999999),task.getResult().getUser().getUid(),task.getResult().getUser().getPhoneNumber());
                            if (user != null){
                                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(KeyUtils.KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
                                        .document(task.getResult().getUser().getUid())
                                        .set(mUser);
                                TinyDBManager tinyDB = TinyDB.getInstance(LoginActivity.this);
                                tinyDB.put("current_user",mUser);
                                new PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext()).putString("uid",mUser.getUserId());
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private String getPhoneNumber(){
        return binding.countryCodePicker.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus() + " " + binding.number.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

I also tried using test phone numbers but that doesn't work either

Comment: "it does not login" doesn't provide information so we can help. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: It worked now. But it takes too long to send the otp and the verification thing. How can I reduce that time

Comment: Try to upgrade your Firebase account which will make a huge difference in receiving OTP.

Comment: uhhhmmm I want to go with the free plan for now. But does the paid plan work better?

Comment: do you have any source which shows that a different account will make any difference @LalremLianBTlung ?

Comment: Have you try using an emulator with google services?

Comment: Yes. It works in emulator and device now. But the device takes too long to login